# How to get own device token?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to get your own device token from my own iPhone? I need it because I want to test Push-Notifications...
Thanks

Comment: maybe you need the UDID, that is different from push notifications token, but that can be obtained without writing an app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use the `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken;` method. Below is an example that will output your devices token as well as set it to a string.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"APN device token: %@", deviceToken);    
    NSString *deviceTokenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
}
```

But, you should really be doing this already though so that you know where to send the notifications for your users, aren't you?

Edit after further clarification comment:

You weren't very specific at all in your question. To answer your more detailed question, you can't display it. As it is unique for each device AND each app. So your token for AppA is not the same as AppB.

Comment: I don't want to write an app.. I only want to get the device token.. Is it not possible to display it in the system settings from iOS?

Comment: You weren't very specific at all in your question. To answer your more detailed question, you can't display it. As it is unique for each device AND each app. So your token for AppA is not the same as AppB.

Comment: very true what Jeremy told + it is different in debug / release mode of the app too!

Comment: @htw "I don't want to write an app" That's why your question is off-topic on StackOverflow. Voting to close.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 Thanks. That was the answer! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The device token needed for push notification you will have in a callback function if you have subscribed to push notification. Until that not, unless you write doen the previous value.

Note the token for app in development / debug mode it is different from release/ad-hoc mode!!!

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
}
```

Please look at [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) tutorial. Also it is not working with simulator, and jailbroken devices